# Get E-Mail Address from Layout do not work

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have the problem when I want to register a new E-Mail to my firebase store.

I have that button in my `activity_register.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
....
```

After that I want to use it to register to the firebase store:

```
fun register(view: View){
        val email: String=R.id.editTextEmailAddress.toString()
        val password=R.id.editTextPassword.javaClass.toString()

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val intent= Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

If I take a look at the debugger there I can see the following:

[Screenshot from Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8ml.png)

It looks like it is an integer. How can I fix that Problem?
I tried to solve it with bindings, but there the inflate is not possible.

Same Problem with the password one row below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are taking the reference to the view instead, you should do like this

```
val emailField = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailAddress)

val passwordField = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword)
```

Now access the text

```
val email = emailField.text.toString()

val password = passwordField.text.toString()
```

Comment: Hello, I get an error for the "text". Unresolved reference: text". I tried that before. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check now